# py Photo Stitching of a Million Files

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, image-stitching

## Background information

I am working on a project where I try to print a huge poster, I allready found a printing company who would be willing to help me print it, but I have to send them the data in one file (preferably as a JPEG), but my project consists of over 2 million files.
Now, that's where the struggle begins; I don't have any bigass server at home which I could use to quickly stitch these 256 by 256 px images together, I only have a humble i7 and 16gb of RAM.

## Method

I am using `PIL.Image` to stitch images together (any alternatives are welcome).

My code works for smaller files, but my input data is a total of 13 gigabytes of JPEG files split into over 2 million files.

```
from PIL import Image

"""
1. create a list with pictures
2. stitch them together vertically

>images are all in the folder D:/tiles/ and named after they'r x and y 
 position: "x_y.jpeg" (e.g.: 2000_642.jpeg)

>vertical lines will be put inside folder D:/output/ and will be named after 
 they'r x-position (in the code variable j) (e.g.: 2000.jpeg)
 
>full poster will be put inside D:/poster.jpeg
"""

def joinVert(j,imagePath):
    # open pictures
    images = [Image.open(x) for x in imagePath]
    # get list with width and height
    widths, heights = zip(*(i.size for i in images))
    # get maximum width and total height to find the size of target image
    max_width = max(widths)
    total_height = sum(heights)
    # create target image
    new_im = Image.new('RGB', (max_width, total_height))
    # y_offset defines the amounts of px to top border -- will increase by 
        # height of last pic
    y_offset = 0
    # iterate trough images and paste them into new image
    for im in images:
      new_im.paste(im, (0,y_offset))
      y_offset += im.size[1]
    # save new picture to output
    tgt='D:/output/'+str(j)+'.jpeg'
    new_im.save(tgt)
    return tgt

def joinHor(path,imagePath):
    # open pictures
    images = [Image.open(x) for x in imagePath]
    # get list with width and height
    widths, heights = zip(*(i.size for i in images))
    # get maximum height and total width to find the size of target image
    max_height = max(heights)
    total_width = sum(widths)
    # create target image
    new_im = Image.new('RGB', (total_width, max_height))
    #x_offset defines the amounts of px to left border -- will increase by 
        # width of last pic
    x_offset = 0
    # iterate trough images and paste them into new image
    for im in images:
      new_im.paste(im, (x_offset,0))
      x_offset += im.size[0]
    # save new picture to path
    new_im.save(path)

# list of paths to output files --> will be stiched together later
targets=[]
for j in range(700,715):
    # create a list with all the pictures in this row
    imagePath = []
    for i in range(700,715):
        imagePath.append("D:/tiles/"+str(j)+"_"+str(i)+".jpeg")
    # join all pictures vertically in the list to one, returns path of outputfile
    targets.append(joinVert(j,imagePath))

joinHor("D:/poster.jpeg",targets)
```

## Problem

AFAIK `PIL.Image` puts all the data in the RAM. My CPU and RAM are not playing along with me, due to the incredible amount of data processed - how would you guys write to a picture file that will be bigger than your RAM? Any ideas are welcome.

Comment: Check out libvips... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vips

Comment: @MarkSetchell Thanks, it worked!